# Installing Android OS into Windows

Tags: android, windows-7, virtualbox

Is it possible to install **android** operating system into a 32-bit **windows 7** system via **virtual box**? If yes please help me do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an AVD.

You could install Android SDK, Eclipse and ADB on a VM of Windows 7, and run the Android in an emulator/virtual device as described. Android OS requires an ARM processor to run natively without VM.

1. Get Virtual Box
2. Install Windows 7 32-bit on Virtual Box
3. Install Eclipse (optional)
4. Install Android SDK
5. Run Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD)
6. Set up Android Emulator with SD Card, and other components you need.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not ([VirtualBox Guest OSes](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes)).
You have to use the Android Emulator (AVD) or take a look at [this](http://androvm.org/blog/) site.

Comment: KCD is right. AVD is the way to go. Need Android Virtual Device or Emulator.